# Insure that all instances of a given COM-visible .NET component share a single AppDomain

Tags: .net, com-interop, appdomain

I am planning to expose a .NET component with a COM interface, and I would like all the instances of the .NET class to share a single Application Domain.

What would be the best way of achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible it will not be easy.

While creating an instance of a type in a known [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) is easy (eg. [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386944.aspx) overload that takes an `AppDomain` reference), the problem will be getting the reference to the target `AppDomain`.

Creating the `AppDomain` and sharing that reference within the current `AppDomain` is easy: a `static` field or property.

Sharing that reference to other AppDomains created by third party code is a problem. I seem to recall parts of the BCL do share statics across domains (essentially they have a single instance per process rather than per `AppDomain`, but this mechanism isn't generally accessible to other assemblies.

It is probably better to understand why you want to be able to do this: there is probably a better solution to your underlying problem: why do you want all instances in a single `AppDomain`?

Comment: Mainly, because there is some overhead involved with initializing the component, and that this cost is isolated on an AppDomain basis. However, the more I read your answer, the more I think that my question does not highlight my pain point (I know it is painful to enumerate processes and AppDomains to find the one I want, but I have already found instructions on how to do these); it was more about how to make such a setup (single process on the .NET side, multiple processes on the COM side) work well with COM interop. Still, thank you.